# Monotonicity of sigma-algebra generator: $A\subset B \rightarrow \sigma(\{E\in A\})\subset \sigma(\{E\in B\})$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

$A,B$ are collections of sets. Does $A\subset B$ implies $\sigma(\{E\in A\})\subset \sigma(\{E\in B\})$? How to prove this?

Comment: Does $\{E\in A\}$ stand for $\{E\mid E\in A\}$? If so then why don't you just write $\sigma(A)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is effectively from the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra generated by certain sets.

The $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(B)$ generated by $B$ is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which contains the sets $B$, and likewise for $A$. Since $A\subseteq B$, this implies that $\sigma(B)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains the sets in $A$, and therefore $\sigma(A)\subseteq\sigma(B)$.